# "& was unexpected at this time" in the Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[jupyter-notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Muh.png)
I've recently run into an issue within Jupyter Notebook where I'm encountering difficulties installing any packages. I'm uncertain whether this is the result of a recent update or if there has been a change in syntax. Regardless, I'm seeking assistance in resolving this matter. It's essential for me to be able to install packages seamlessly within Jupyter Notebook to continue with my work effectively. If you could provide guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: And if you do upload a screenshot. Make sure it isn't just a tiny bit out of context. For example, in your screenshot we get no information about the kernel? Everything you posted and more could (**& should**) easily be stated and shown as text so it is informative and searchable. See my comments adding further context to manojlds excellent answer to see why you should have stated the kernel being used or how you are using the Jupyter interface, such as whether you are online or have installed on your system with Anaconda/conda.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
%pip install numpy
```

Note the `%` instead of `!`. It's a built-in magic command available and should work better if your system has some weird issues with shells and paths etc. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip

Comment: The magic install commands work better than the exclamation point because they specifically insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the active notebook is running. More context on the magic install commands for both `pip` and `conda` can be found at links [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).  [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why ...

Comment: <cotninued> the exclamation point may lead to issues. **Importantly, the magic version of `pip install` also works in JupyterLite which I suspect the OP is using given the odd error in the screenshot.** It is the most universal way and the best practice to install things in current Jupyter ecosystem, working in all modern Jupyter including Google Colab now. Consider anything saying to use an exclamation point with installation commands as outdated and so be wary of any of the associated advice.